# Print IP address in Server. Log for wildfly 10 server

Tags: logging, wildfly, wildfly-10

As of now in the log file I can see
17:08:19,813 INFO [CLASS NAME] (**default task - 1**) Hello.

Now I want to show **IP address** where application is deployed instead of **default task** in the log.

For example:
17:08:19,813 INFO [CLASS NAME] (**10.123.456.789:8380 - 1**) Hello.

What should I need to change in my standalone.xml file for the wildfly 10.1.0 server.

I am using below pattern to print the log.

"%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%h` for the short host name or `%H` for the fully qualified host name. The [WildFly Documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/24/Admin_Guide.html#pattern-formatter) has a table of all the valid patterns. Note that the value "default task - 1" is the thread name.

With CLI you can change the pattern at runtime without having to reboot the server.

```
/subsystem=logging/pattern-formatter=PATTERN:write-attribute(name=pattern, value="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%h) %s%E%n")
```